# rails - form_tag connect to custom function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

New to rails!!!
How do i make my "Send" button call a function (sendmail) which sends an email?
This is what I have so far....
The sendmail in events_controller does not called!
And I have an event in my model, and i am running rails 3.2.3

show.html.erb:

```
<p><b>Send Results</b></p>
<%= form_tag("/events", :method => "get") do %>
<p><label for="email_recipient">Email recipient</label>:
<%= text_field 'email', 'Email recipient' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :events do
      member do 
          get '/sendmail', :as => :sendmail
      end
  end
```

events_controller.rb

```
   def sendmail
        puts "sendmail"
        Emailer.deliver_results_email
        return if request.xhr?
        render :text => 'Message sent successfully'
  end
```

emailer.rb

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  #default from: "from@example.com"
  def results_email
    puts "RESULTS EMAIL"
    #NEVER GETS THIS FAR.....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. In your `routes.rb` you have put the `sendmail` action inside a `member` block. This would generate a route like this:

```
/events/:id/sendmail
```

If the sendmail action is kindda generic and don't need to be applied on a single 'event', maybe you should put it on a `collection` block, so your route would be like this:

```
/events/sendmail
```

Second, if you run `rake routes | grep sendmail` in your console, you will get something like this outputed:

```
sendmail_event GET /events/:id/sendmail events#sendmail
```

What this line is saying is that you have a route configured and you have a helper route method named `sendmail_event_path` that you can use to facilitate the understanding of your views, etc. So in your view it would be something like this:

```
<%= form_tag sendmail_event_path(@event.id) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When you click the submit button the form would be `POSTED` to the sendmail action of your `events_controller`.

I suggest you to change your route to a `collection`, and change to `:post`, so you can use it without the event isntance.